# Remove first occurrence of elements in a vector from another vector

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a character vector, including some elements that are duplicates e.g.

```
v <- c("d09", "d11", "d13", "d01", "d02", "d10", "d13")
```

And another vector that includes single counts of those characters e.g.

```
x <- c("d10", "d11", "d13")
```

I want to remove only the *first* occurrence of each element in `x` from the 2nd vector `v`. In this example, `d13` occurs in `x` and twice in `v`, but only the first match is removed from `v` and the duplicate is kept. Thus, I want to end up with:

```
"d09", "d01", "d02", "d13"
```

I've been trying various things e.g. `z <- v[!(v %in% x)]`  but it keeps removing *all* instances of the characters in `x`, not just the first, so I end up with this instead:

```
"d09", "d01", "d02"
```

What can I do to only remove one instance of a duplicated element?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `match` and negative indexing.

```
v[-match(x, v)]
```

produces

```
[1] "d09" "d01" "d02" "d13"
```

`match` only returns the location of the first match of a value, which we use to our advantage here.

Note that `%in%` and `is.element` are degenerate versions of `match`.  Compare:

```
match(x, v)            # [1] 6 2 3
match(x, v) > 0        # [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
x %in% v               # [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
is.element(x, v)       # [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

The last three are all the same, and are basically the coerced to logical version of the first (in fact, see code for `%in%` and `is.element`).  In doing so you lose key information, which is the location of the first match of `x` in `v` and are left only knowing that `x` values exist in `v`.

The converse, `v %in% x` means something different from what you want, which is "which values in `v` are in `x`", which won't meet your requirement since all duplicate values will satisfy that condition.