# How to remove items in a vector from another vector

Tags: r

I have two vectors:

```
a = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4) 
b = c(1)
```

I want to remove the *first* match of `b` from `a`. Thus, here only the first `1` is removed from `a`:

```
c = c(1,2,2,3,3,4,4)
```

The order of items in `a` is not important.

I tried this code:

```
a[a != b]
a[! a %in% b]
```

Both results are:

```
[1] 2 2 3 3 4 4.
```

All numbers of 1 are removed. However, I only want to remove the specific item in `b` from `a`.

If `b = c(1, 1, 2)`, then I wish the result

```
[1] 2 3 3 4 4

a[-(1:3)]
```

The above code could lead to the result of `[1] 2 3 3 4 4`. However, I wish it could be more flexible. For example when the order of items are unknown or random:

```
a = c(3,4,3,1,2,2,1,4)
```

How can I do it using R?

Comment: Something like `a[-(1:3)]`?

Comment: Thanks, jaySf. a[-(1:3)] may work when the order of items in a are fixed. However, what if a = c(3,4,3,1,2,2,1,4), for example?

Comment: If you don't have duplicates in `b`, you could have used `match` as described here: [Remove first occurrence of elements in a vector from another vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30129684/use-a-lookup-vector-to-remove-first-occurrence-of-its-elements-in-another-vector)

Comment: Related: [*Find a sequence of numbers in a vector*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48660606/find-a-sequence-of-numbers-in-a-vector)

Comment: also related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16388405/4137985 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/46657373/4137985

Answer (score 5):

`vecsets` package can perform standard set operations, while retaining duplicates:

```
vecsets::vsetdiff( c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4), c(1) )
## [1] 1 2 2 3 3 4 4

vecsets::vsetdiff( c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4), c(1,1,2) )
## [1] 2 3 3 4 4
```

Note that it will preserve the order of the first argument. Using your last example:

```
vecsets::vsetdiff( c(3,4,3,1,2,2,1,4), c(1,1,2) )
## [1] 3 4 3 2 4
```

Answer (score 4):

Taking inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46658375/4137985) to one of the questions I linked in comment, you can use `fsetdiff` from the package [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table).
It takes `all` as argument, which avoids having only the unique values returned, as happens with `setdiff`:

```
library(data.table)

# with your first example (b = c(1)):
unlist(fsetdiff(data.table(v1=a), data.table(v1=b), all = TRUE))
# v11 v12 v13 v14 v15 v16 v17 
#  1   2   2   3   3   4   4

# with second example (b = c(1, 1, 2)):
unlist(fsetdiff(data.table(v1=a), data.table(v1=b), all = TRUE))
# v11 v12 v13 v14 v15 
#  2   3   3   4   4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `which()`

```
a = c(3, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4)
a
## [1] 3 4 3 1 2 2 1 4

b = 1

a[- which(a %in% b)[1]]
## [1] 3 4 3 2 2 1 4
```

Case *b* has two elements:

```
b2 = c(1, 2)

sapply(seq_along(b1), function(x) a <<- a[- which(a == x)[1]])[[2]]
## [1] 3 4 3 2 1 4
```

Or three...

```
b3 <- c(1, 2, 3)

sapply(seq_along(b1), function(x) a <<- a[- which(a == x)[1]])[[3]]
# [1] 4 3 2 1 4
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help! It works fine when the list of b contains one value. I am now trying a more complex list. For example, b = c(1,1,2).

Comment: @luyan There might be something better, but the simple `for(x in b) a <- a[-which(a == x)[1]]` works. Do this on a copy of `a`  if you don't want to mutate it.

Comment: @luyan glad it works, but in R I tend to regard any use of a for loop as a failure of imagination. On the other hand, if a quick and dirty loop does what you want and the problem sizes are small enough that efficiency isn't a concern, there isn't much reason to spend a lot of time coming up with a vectorized approach.

Comment: @JohnColeman I've added a vectorized approach, thanks for your inspiration.

Comment: In response to a comment on a now deleted post referring to this one; repeated iterations of a function like this feels like a case where a for loop in R is actually the right thing to do. The second half of John Coleman's comment about is particularly relevant. This isn't the kind of operation that R is natively good at, so if more efficiency is needed,    moving to a C/C++ function is likely to be more fruitful than trying to rework into the *apply paradigm. See perhaps the Rcpp package, which makes this relatively easy.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for your comment, I solved this primarily to meet the challenge.

Comment: @Aaron Good points. Knowing when a loop is appropriate in R is one of the things that I still haven't mastered. I use them often enough, but when I do so I have trouble shaking the feeling that I am missing a more elegant solution. I have had too many occasions where I have written complicated loop-based solutions only to later find a 1-liner which does the same thing much faster.

Comment: @Aaron I just looked at my copy of "Advanced R" and in its chapter on Rcpp it gives as a typical use-case "Loops that can’t be easily vectorised because subsequent iterations depend on previous ones", which seems to be a good description of this current problem.

Comment: @JohnColeman: I've had that happen to me on many occasions too. :) Though that's becoming less and less often, and now I'm actually more likely to know that something could be done with *apply, but to chose a for loop instead for quicker writing and more readable code. I'm learning to optimize my time over the computer's time. :)

Comment: Using the global assignment inside a `sapply` loop is a good case for using `Reduce` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the following is the best solution (the `vecsets` approach strikes me as the best), but @Aaron's comment about possibly using Rcpp struck me as interesting. This is the first time I used that package. If nothing else, the fact that I was able to get working code in less than 20 minutes underscores his point that Rcpp makes it relatively easy:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('
  NumericVector difference(NumericVector xs, NumericVector ys){
    int m = xs.size();
    int n = ys.size();
    float flag = 1 + abs(max(xs)) + abs(max(ys)); //occurs in neither xs nor ys
    NumericVector zs = clone(xs);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
      double y = ys[i];
      int j = 0;
      while(j < m && zs[j]!= y) j++;
      if(j < m) zs[j] = flag;
    }
    int count = 0;
    for(int k = 0; k < m; k++){
      if(zs[k] < flag) count++;
    }
    NumericVector ws(count);
    int k = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
      if(zs[j] < flag){
        ws[k] = zs[j];
        k++;
      }
    }
    return ws;
  }
')
```

After you source this:

```
> a = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4)
> b = c(1,2,1)
> difference(a,b)
[1] 2 3 3 4 4
```

Since this was my first attempt at such code, I'm sure that it could be improved in multiple ways.

Answer (score 0):

A little frustrating, the syntactical order, but `Reduce` and `which` do it with just Base R.

`Reduce(b, a) a[-which(a==b)[1]], a, b)`